# Slide down/up overlay panel on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, scrolltop

basically I'm trying to achieve this effect... http://www.vtcreative.fr panel scrolling over the content area.

I've tried to un-minify the js and work it out but struggling to do so!

Would I be right in thinking that the content div is a fixed position, once the the overlay (header) panel reaches to the top using scrollTop() this changes the content position to relative, allowing that to scroll?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have a code sample?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here:

```
header.stop().addClass("overlay-active")
content.removeClass("active");
```

the complete code is:

```
function Scroll() {
    if(responsive_viewport >= 768) {
        var e = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(e < previousPos && e < 20) {
            body.removeClass("b-content-pos");
            content.removeClass("active");
            okScroll = 0;
            setTimeout(function () {
                loaderLogo.addClass("active")
            }, 500);
            setTimeout(function () {
                header.stop().delay(1e3).removeClass("overlay-active")
            }, 1e3);
            loaderLine.addClass("alt")
        }
....
```

Comment: Thanks hamburger for the starting point. I've managed to get something to work loosely based on the above code.

If I get time will post the example on jsfiddle.

Comment: dont forget to vote ;)

Comment: I would do, but as a new user unable to vote

Comment: but at least you can accept the answer :)